# ¿Como puedo invertir un Layout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Lo que quiero es invertir un **Layout** *(que se vea alreves)*, para que tengan una idea es algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas Alejandro, esto es un foro para resolver errores de programación, no para hacer el trabajo a los demás

Comment: No peor se supone que puedes mandarme una articulo o un plugin, nunca mande a que me des una aplicación como la de la imagen.

Comment: Alejandro, yo puedo ayudarte pero por favor, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas.

Comment: por curiosidad cual app es esa de la imagen?

Comment: HUD Widget creo, es muy buena.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta rotar el Layout padre que contiene todo lo de tu vista mediante el XML

- `android:rotationX`
- `android:rotationY`

Podrias ir tratando de jugar un poco con los valores para ajustarlo a tu conveniencias, por ejemplo podrias invertir el layout en X:

```
android:rotationX="-180"
```

Si deseas hacerlo desde codigo java existen tambien los metodos para modificarlo

- `view.setRotationY(float)`
- `view.setRotationX(float)`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! si pudiera darte mas puntos te los diera.